# uiview hierarchy and manage uievent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uievent

I have layout witch is shown in the figure below. It has 2 layers. First marked as C is transparent uiview with added pan gesture recognizer. It is used to syncing setting content offset of A and B view, which are on second layer. Layer means uiview which is directly add to uiviewcontroller's view.

The view A is uitableview with same option to select.

My problem is how to transfer tap event from C uiview to uitableviewcell of A uitableview. 
I tried many approach:

i.e using:

-(id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

-(BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

in UIView C, but the problem is that i have two layers.

[image]

Comment: Why not get rid of C and use the fact that a tableView is a s scrollView, override viewDidScroll and synchronize A to B/B to A this way?

Comment: View A and B are embedded in scrollview. First i tried build my layout interaction by viewDidScroll, but in this method as parameter got only UIScrollview. And if i manually manipulate contentoffset for example A, i don't get real user action. Another problem is that view A and B must react on pan gesture which start in view B and finish in view A